# Can anyone help me like operator in sql?

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to search for the name in the database. However, I do not want to type the full name of the user. So I want to use the like function in SQL. When I use the like function, the result does not display anything. I still need to type full name of the user.

```
    <form action="SearchStaff.php" method="post">   
    <fieldset style="background-color: #424242">
        <table style="color: #141042">
            
             <tr>
                <td>STAFF NAME</td> 
                <td> <input type="text" name="USER_NAME" placeholder="STAFF NAME" style="text- 
                 transform: uppercase;" size="40" > </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <div><br>       
        <button type="submit" type="button" name="submit">Search Staff Name</button>
        </div>

        </fieldset>

        </form>
        
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["USER_NAME"])){
                $B_title  = strtoupper($_POST["USER_NAME"]);
                
                //sql statement
                include_once("DB_Connect.php");
                $sql = "SELECT 
                       TS_ID, TS_DATE, TS_DDATE, TS_HOUR, TRAINING_NAME,TRAINING_HOUR, USER_NAME 
                        FROM 
                                TRAINING_STATUS TS,
                                USER_INFO UI,
                                TRAINING B
                        WHERE
                                TS.TRAINING_ID = B.TRAINING_ID
                        AND
                                TS.USER_ID = UI.USER_ID
                        AND
                                UI.USER_NAME LIKE '$B_title%'
                        ";
                include("sql.php");
                if($_SESSION['UserType'] == 'admin'){
                   print    '<table style="width:100%">
                            <tr style="background-color:#6154FE">
                                <th>STAFF NAME</th> 
                                <th>TRAINING NAME</th>  
                                <th>ATTEND DATE</th>
                                <th>ATTEND TIME</th>
                                <th>TRAINING HOUR</th>
                            </tr>';
                  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                        if($row['USER_NAME'] == $B_title && $B_title != null){
                            DisplayAdmin($row);
                            $loop = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
           ?>
           </div>
       </center>    
   </body>
```

Comment: please include your sql.php, we have no idea how you use your $sql variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

```
UI.USER_NAME LIKE '%".$B_title."%'
```

concat in php . right? :D